# Parsing this string for particular information in bash

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, grep

I'm writing a bash script and a portion of it requires me to retrieve the title of the assignment and the due date from a string by parsing it for useful information and discarding the rest.

I've tried using sed a little bit but can't seem to get it to work how I want.

one of the things in the script that I tried was

`LABS=$(sed 's/<a.*/a>//' $LABS)`

```
["<a href=\"https://classroom.github.com/a/WOWerwCz\">lab01</a>",
    "Lab 1", bblearn_content_base + "/resources/Labs/1.html",
    "7/3/2019", 1,
    "<a href=\"https://classroom.github.com/a/k3dVwTMy\">lab02</a>",
    "Lab 2", bblearn_content_base + "/resources/Labs/2.html",
    "7/12/2019", 1,
    "<a href=\"https://classroom.github.com/a/z1chUDd4\">lab03</a>",
    "Lab 3", bblearn_content_base + "/resources/Labs/3.html",
    "7/20/2019", 1,
    "<a href=\"https://classroom.github.com/a/iHbdXqs4\">lab04</a>",
    "Lab 4", bblearn_content_base + "/resources/Labs/4.html",
    "7/31/2019", 1,
    "<a href=\"https://classroom.github.com/a/WgyMWn68\">lab05</a>",
    "Lab 5", bblearn_content_base + "/resources/Labs/5.html",
    "8/5/2019", 1,
    "<a href=\"https://classroom.github.com/a/4anRjuDB\">lab06</a>",
    "Lab 6", bblearn_content_base + "/resources/Labs/6.html",
    "8/10/2019", 1,
    "<a href=\"https://classroom.github.com/a/qTyBR1R8\">lab07</a>",
    "Lab 7", bblearn_content_base + "/resources/Labs/7.html",
    "8/16/2019", 1,
    "<a href=\"https://classroom.github.com/a/UIJsxfA5\">lab08</a>",
    "Lab 8", bblearn_content_base + "/resources/Labs/8.html",
    "8/22/2019", 1,
    "<a href=\"https://classroom.github.com/a/XYUPMOiC\">lab09</a>",
    "Lab 9", bblearn_content_base + "/resources/Labs/9.html",
    "8/25/2019", 1,
    "<a href=\"https://classroom.github.com/a/ZJQ70-dy\">lab10</a>",
    "Lab 10", bblearn_content_base + "/resources/Labs/10.html",
    "9/1/2019", 1
]
```

Essentially what I need to do is remove everything that isn't "Lab x" and the date that follows, but I'm struggling to figure out how.

Comment: @adam I think your question lacks clarification. Can you give us an example of the result that you are expecting from the script you are writing?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you could write all your processing task in one `awk` script.
But here is a little `awk` script that does the task:

`script.awk`

```
BEGIN {FPAT="\"[^\"]+";}  # extract the first field between " into variable $1
NR % 3 == 0 { # on each 3rd line
    print labName, substr($1,2); # print labName and $1 without initial "
}
{             # on each line 
    labName = substr($1,2); # read the labName (or whatever there) from $1 (without initial ")
}
```

running:

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

or one liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FPAT="\"[^\"]+";}NR % 3 == 0 {print labName, substr($1,2);}{labName = substr($1,2);}' input.txt
```

output:

```
Lab 1 7/3/2019
Lab 2 7/12/2019
Lab 3 7/20/2019
Lab 4 7/31/2019
Lab 5 8/5/2019
Lab 6 8/10/2019
Lab 7 8/16/2019
Lab 8 8/22/2019
Lab 9 8/25/2019
Lab 10 9/1/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
LABS=$(sed '/<a href/d;/^[][]/d;s/\s*\("[^"]*"\).*/\1/' $LABS)
```

**output**

```
"Lab 1"
"7/3/2019"
"Lab 2"
"7/12/2019"
"Lab 3"
"7/20/2019"
"Lab 4"
"7/31/2019"
"Lab 5"
"8/5/2019"
"Lab 6"
"8/10/2019"
"Lab 7"
"8/16/2019"
"Lab 8"
"8/22/2019"
"Lab 9"
"8/25/2019"
"Lab 10"
"9/1/2019"
```

**explanation**

```
/<a href/d                # remove all lines with hrefs
;
/^[][]/d                  # remove all lines starting with [ or ] 
;
s/\s*\("[^"]*"\).*/\1/    # remove leading spaces, and extract content between "..."
```